# Magento 2.4.4 All Content fields not displayed in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

I have an issue after upgrade of 2.4.3 to 2.4.4. Description field on product and any content type text field on categories / pages / static blocks is not displaying in Admin. Using php 7.4. Tried to use php 8.1 but encountered too many other errors with Modules so it is just not possible yet. Is there any workaround to resolve this.. The attributes just seem to be hidden. No text box or label appears..[image] Everything else is working and field displays on the front end.. but cannot edit content in Admin.

Comment: looks to be something to do with pagebuilder as when attribute is change to TextArea instead of pagebuilder it appears on the product however this cant be done for all the static blocks\ categories content fields.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by setting the correct folder permissions on the magento directories and subdirectories.. Everything else worked bar the pagebuilder which was strange